# ASP.NET MVC 3 Httppost method display error 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my project with ASP classic get parameter with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefIdLabel.Text = Request.Params["RefId"];      
}
```

but in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Httppost method not working to get parameter and display error 404 not found . parameter is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult callbackfrombank()
{
   string RefId = Request.Params["RefId"];
}
```

why? please help me. thanks ...

- post parameter from another server to my server.

Comment: And what does your client markup or JS look like?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: You post to this action somehow, either using JavaScript or a plain old HTML form. However you are doing this is where the problem likely lies.

Comment: I do not know how the server post parameter.

Comment: Can you provide your routing records? MVC and "ASP Classic" are two completely different technologies

Answer (score 1):

Use `FormCollection` to pass submitted data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult callbackfrombank(FormCollection collection)
{
   string RefId = collection["RefId"];
}
```

Comment: post parameter from another server to my server.

Comment: It's much easier to just make it a parameter on the method, i.e. `callbackfrombank(string refId)`. MVC will bind that parameter to any value in the request where it can find it (query string, form variable, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work for you,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult callbackfrombank(string refId)
{
   string RefId = refId;
}
```

Comment: when call callbackfrombank action with httppost display error 404 not found.

Comment: How do you access the method? to get this, you have to do a POST request via form or JS

Comment: try to get parameter from another server. no post paramter.

Comment: if no post parameter then it should be get request. if it is get request, remove the `[HttpPost]` and it will works for you